# How to execute loop # of times based on user console input in Perl?

Tags: perl

I want to print a set of N 4-digit numbers depending on a parameter provided by a user. I have the following code printing one random digit. So far,  I have a piece of code generating probably good pseudo-random number.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );
use feature qw( say );

my @digits = ('0'..'9');
my $len = 4;
my $num = '';

for (1..$len) {
$num .= $chars[int rand @chars];
}

say $num;
```

I would like to execute a script as `./a.pl 5` to get the following output:

```
1342
6322
7589
3478
3457
```

What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: If i understand you correctly, your question is regarding how you can get the parameter "5" of the "./a.pl 5" call? if so: my $len = $ARGV[0]

Comment: Yes, how to get the parameter and use it in for loop to get the result.

Comment: ok, so my first comment should help you. The parameters are in the @ARGV array.

Answer (score 4):

Read arguments from [`@ARGV`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html). There is more than one way to do it:

(the `//` defined-or operator requires `use 5.10.1` or higher)

```perl
# Use a default value if unspecified.
my $x = shift // 42;
```

```perl
# Argument is required.
my $x = shift // die "usage: $0 ...\n";
```

[`shift`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) shifts the first element out of the `@_` array by default, but uses `@ARGV` outside of
subroutine scope.
`$ARGV[0]` would have the same effect in the snippets above, without modifying the argument array.

[`Getopt`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) is commonly used for more complex argument handling.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the command-line arguments from `@ARGV`. So, something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );
use feature qw( say );

# shift() without arguments outside of a subroutine
# will work on @ARGV.
# // 1 means "give it a default value of 1"
my $count = shift // 1;

my @digits = ('0'..'9');
my $len = 4;

for (1 .. $count) {

  # Move the declaration of $num inside the loop
  my $num = '';

  for (1..$len) {
    $num .= $digits[int rand @digits];
  }

  say $num;
}
```

But, I think you're doing too much work in building up the number. You basically want a number between 0 and 9999 - so ask for that.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );
use feature qw( say );

my $count = shift // 1;

my $len = 4;
my $limit = 10 ** $len; # 10**4 = 10_000

for (1 .. $count) {
  my $num = int rand $limit;

  say $num;
}
```

This has a small problem, as numbers less than 1,000 won't have zeros at the start. We can fix that with `sprintf()`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );
use feature qw( say );

# shift() without arguments outside of a subroutine
# will work on @ARGV.
# // 1 means "give it a default value of 1"
my $count = shift // 1;

my $len = 4;
my $limit = 10 ** $len; # 10**4 = 10_000

for (1 .. $count) {
  # Slight complication here. We want to use $len in
  # the string, but it would get joined to the 's'
  # that follows it. So we use the (slightly obscure)
  # ${len} syntax which fixes that.
  my $num = sprintf "%0${len}s", int rand $limit;

  say $num;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please review a short version of pseudo random number generator.

You can specify how many numbers are required to be generated on the command line, number positions of digits is fixed in code `my $len = 4;`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $count = shift || 10;
my $len = 4;

printf "%04d\n", (int rand 10**$len) while $count--;
```

Sample of output `numgen.pl 10`

```
8730
1669
3433
3352
7654
5908
4148
6890
5905
3840
```

And extended version of the code, where you able to specify

- how many numbers to be generated are desired
- how many digit positions should be in a number
- brief help on usage
- generate **manual page** for program

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);
use Pod::Usage;

my @args = (
        'count|c=i',
        'length|l=i',
        'help|h',
        'man|m',
        'debug|d'
    );

my %opt = (
            count   => 10,
            length  => 4,
            debug   => 0
        );

GetOptions(\%opt, @args) or pod2usage(2);

pod2usage(1) if $opt{help};
pod2usage(-exitval => 0, -verbose => 2) if $opt{man};

printf "%04d\n", (int rand 10**$opt{length}) while $opt{count}--;


__END__

=pod

=head1 NAME

numgen.pl - pseudo random number generator 

=head1 SYNOPSIS

numgen.pl [options]

 Options:
    -c,--count  count of generated numbers
    -l,--length position length of numbers
    -h,--help   brief help message
    -m,--man    full documentation
    -d,--debug  output debug information
    
=head1 OPTIONS

=over 4

=item B<-c,--count>

Count specifies how many numbers are required to generate

=item B<-l,--lenght>

Length specifies number positions in a number

=item B<-h,--help>

Print a brief help message and exits.

=item B<-m,--man>

Prints the manual page and exits.

=item B<-d,--debug>

Print debug information.

=back

=head1 DESCRIPTION

B<This program> generates pseudo-random numbers for some purpose

=head1 AUTHOR

Polar Bear Aug 27, 2020

=head1 REPORTING BUGS

E-mail L<mailto:bugs@inter.net>

=head1 COPYRIGHT

Copyright information

=head1 SEE ALSO

L<The Perl Home page|http://www.perl.org/>

=cut
```

Sample of output `numgen.pl -c 5 -l 12`

```
686567922196
677796459148
718949335898
869407116059
203852689254
```

Output of `numgen.pl -h`

```
Usage:
    numgen.pl [options]

     Options:
            -c,--count      count of generated numbers
            -l,--length     position length of numbers
            -h,--help       brief help message
            -m,--man        full documentation
            -d,--debug      output debug information

Options:
    -c,--count
        Count specifies how many numbers are required to generate

    -l,--lenght
        Length specifies number positions in a number

    -h,--help
        Print a brief help message and exits.

    -m,--man
        Prints the manual page and exits.

    -d,--debug
        Print debug information.
```

Output of `numgen.pl --man`

```
NAME
    numgen.pl - pseudo random number generator

SYNOPSIS
    numgen.pl [options]

     Options:
            -c,--count      count of generated numbers
            -l,--length     position length of numbers
            -h,--help       brief help message
            -m,--man        full documentation
            -d,--debug      output debug information

OPTIONS
    -c,--count
        Count specifies how many numbers are required to generate

    -l,--lenght
        Length specifies number positions in a number

    -h,--help
        Print a brief help message and exits.

    -m,--man
        Prints the manual page and exits.

    -d,--debug
        Print debug information.

DESCRIPTION
    This program generates pseudo-random numbers for some purpose

AUTHOR
    Polar Bear Aug 27, 2020

REPORTING BUGS
    E-mail <mailto:bugs@inter.net>

COPYRIGHT
    Copyright information

SEE ALSO
    The Perl Home page <http://www.perl.org/>
```

See [Getopt::Long](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html), [Pod::Usage](https://perldoc.perl.org/Pod/Usage.html)